# Using ripple authentication fails on azure mobile services (.net backend)

Tags: cordova, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services, ripple

My setup:

- azure mobile service with .net backend, configured with google
- Phonegap (VS2013 with tools for cordova CTP3)
- The service works fine with a Android device

Problem:

- Authentication with ripple does not work (dialog does not close)

Using ripple, when I call client.login() the authentication dialog appears, it authenticates, but the popup does not close. And the done() callback is never called. The url in the popup is something like: `https://localhost:44307/login/done#token=%7B%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22Google%3A1...`

I'm not sure if it's supposed to work, but using the html client (downloaded from managment portal) works fine with authentication. I've tried disabling proxies in ripple, and recrating the project with no luck.

Update: I'm using default client, nothing special here

```
//  
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
  var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
        'https://my-app-service.azure-mobile.net/',
        //'https://localhost:44307/',
        'jFWBtWeZsRaerKJzkCVC........');

var service = {
    isSettingsLoaded: false,
    saved: null,

    login: function() {
        var self = this;
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        client.login('google').done(function(d) {
                // This is not called when using Ripple
            }
        );
        return dfd.promise;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Regard

Larsi

Comment: In what capacity are you using ripple? Can you share the code in question? And is there a reason you cannot use the Mobile Services HTML SDK for login? This would be the recommended way for PhoneGap.

Comment: @mattchenderson, thanks for looking into this. I've updated question with some code. I'm would like to use ripple since its faster than updating my device. I'm not sure what you mean by MS HTML SDK - are there another way I should do the login?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Once I'm done logging into google using ripple, I just see a blank screen in the authentication popup window. The done function never gets called, just like the OP said.

Comment: I met the same issue with @oalbrecht , and the mainly error message is "missing exec:ADALProxy.tokenCacheReadItems" , it seems that there are something wrong with Cordova Briage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the fix was to add your apps url to your allowed external redirects.

see step 7 in [How to: Configure your Mobile App Service for External Redirect URLs.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth)